# Python BeautifulSoup remove items with <br/> tags from list

Tags: python, html, list, beautifulsoup, list-comprehension

I have a BeautifulSoup object (web page), and I've honed in on one HTML paragraph of interest. It has several items in it, and I'd like to clean out the junk (anything other than text).

I have the items from the paragraph in a list after calling the paragraph's Contents attribute (e.g. paragraph_name.contents), but need help clearing out the items with HTML tags in the list.

Here's what the list looks like:

```
[u'\n',
 <span>Early Education Enrollment: 0</span>,
 <br/>,
 u'\r\n        Elementary Enrollment: 231',
 <br/>,
 u'\r\n        Middle School Enrollment: 118',
 <br/>,
 u'\r\n        High School Enrollment: 121',
 <br/>,
 u'\r\n        Total Enrollment: 470',
 <br/>,
 u'\n',
 <span>I20: True</span>,
 <br/>,
 u'\r\n                                                Grade Levels: K - 12',
 <br/>,
 u'\r\n        Year Founded: 1999',
 <br/>,
 u'\n',
 <span>Other Accreditation: AdvancED, SACS</span>,
 u'\n']
```

Here is all the code you'll need to recreate the exact issue I'm having on your machine so we can truly work the same problem:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
# the sample html as a BeautifulSoup Object:
soup = BS('<p>\n<span>Early Education Enrollment: 0</span><br/>\r\n        Elementary Enrollment: 231<br/>\r\n        Middle School Enrollment: 118<br/>\r\n        High School Enrollment: 121<br/>\r\n        Total Enrollment: 470<br/>\n<span>I20: True</span><br/>\r\n                                                Grade Levels: K - 12<br/>\r\n        Year Founded: 1999<br/>\n<span>Other Accreditation: AdvancED, SACS</span>\n</p>', 'lxml')
# hone in on the paragraph I want to parse through:
target_p = soup.find('p')
# organize paragraph items into a list, although including junk for now:
dirty_list = target_p.contents
# clean up list using method I need help with:
clean_list =
```

I figured list comprehensions were the way to go, but can't figure out how to hone in on the html tags. This doesn't work:

```
clean_list = [x for x in dirty_list if x != '<br/>']
```

Thank you!

Comment: From the representation in the list you can tell that those `<br/>` aren't strings. Otherwise they'd look like `u'<br/>'` or `'<br/>'`, the spans aren't either btw.

Comment: Ok, yes, you're right, they're not strings, so how do I access them to remove them? How can I say "Remove all items that are an html tag, specifically '<br/>' tags?

Comment: Without knowing too much about  beautifulsoup, `clean_list = [x for x in dirty_list if repr(x) != '<br/>']` would be a simple approach. But probably you want to further check any nested nodes for more text.

Comment: Thank you schwobaseggl, I'll read up on repr(). :)

Comment: Do that :) `list` uses the `__repr__` of each element for its own `__str__` output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what output format you are looking for. Using `soup.p.text` will give you all the text, but this will include leading spaces. Python can be used to split the text into lines and strip the extra space from each line. This can then be joined back together if required:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

soup = BS('<p>\n<span>Early Education Enrollment: 0</span><br/>\r\n        Elementary Enrollment: 231<br/>\r\n        Middle School Enrollment: 118<br/>\r\n        High School Enrollment: 121<br/>\r\n        Total Enrollment: 470<br/>\n<span>I20: True</span><br/>\r\n                                                Grade Levels: K - 12<br/>\r\n        Year Founded: 1999<br/>\n<span>Other Accreditation: AdvancED, SACS</span>\n</p>', 'lxml')
print '\n'.join(line.strip() for line in soup.p.text.split('\n'))
```

Giving you:

```
Early Education Enrollment: 0
Elementary Enrollment: 231
Middle School Enrollment: 118
High School Enrollment: 121
Total Enrollment: 470
I20: True
Grade Levels: K - 12
Year Founded: 1999
Other Accreditation: AdvancED, SACS
```